# Rich Text Editing - Like E-mail App in iOS (replying to an html email)

Tags: iphone, sdk, editing, richtext

I just realized that if I get an html based email, and then reply to it, I'm able to actually modify all of the text, which may or may not be in all different colors, fonts, bold, etc.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on behind the scenes here?  It was my understanding that there isn't any way, currently, to do rich text editing within iOS.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

FYI:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/
https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/Examples/TextEditor